# WSO2 Identity Server with Multiple IP Domains (Hybrid Cloud Topology)

Tags: wso2, identity, hybrid

Could you please clarify if it is possible to configure a WSO2 Identity Server answering and serving requests from multiple IP domains, like for example an internal company domain, as well as an external official IP domain.

Today, the dashboard access functionality has a number of hard-coded link references in its XML setup files.

Is such hybrid configuration supported in the WSO2 Carbon and IdP server framework, or should it be handled by an external proxy gateway, translating all requests and host names?

Thanks in advance for your feedback and guidance.

Comment: Probably not possible via WSO2 console. As a workaround,would it possible for you to have different entity Ids configured in WSO2 per domain and your application (service provider) to refer the entity ID based upon the domain being accessed ?